# How to manage key conflict handler of different commands in multipage editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, command

I have multipage editor and i'm using different commands in two pages with same key sequence 'M3+O'. I am getting key conflicting handlers.

Error:

```
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+O:
      Binding(ALT+O,
            ParameterizedCommand(Command(adt.tools.wda_com.sap.adt.wda.controller.ui.addmethcommand,Add Method,
                ,
                Category(org.eclipse.core.commands.categories.autogenerated,Uncategorized,Commands that were either auto-generated or have no category,true),
                org.eclipse.ui.internal.MakeHandlersGo@2f2e3d,
                ,,true),null),
            org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
            com.sap.adt.wda.controller.ui.contextTabScope,,,system)
        Binding(ALT+O,
            ParameterizedCommand(Command(adt.tools.wda_com.sap.adt.wda.controller.ui.addnodecommand,Add Node,

        ,
                Category(org.eclipse.core.commands.categories.autogenerated,Uncategorized,Commands that were either auto-generated or have no category,true),
                org.eclipse.ui.internal.MakeHandlersGo@184af18,
                ,,true),null),
            org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
            com.sap.adt.wda.controller.ui.contextTabScope,,,system)
```

Extensions:

```xml
  <extension
             point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
          <key
                commandId="adt.tools.wda_com.sap.adt.wda.controller.ui.addmethcommand"
                contextId="com.sap.adt.wda.controller.ui.contextScope"
                schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
                sequence="M3+O">
          </key>
          <key
                commandId="adt.tools.wda_com.sap.adt.wda.controller.ui.addnodecommand"
                contextId="com.sap.adt.wda.controller.ui.contextScope"
                schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
                sequence="M3+O">
          </key>
    </extension>
```

My own Context:

```xml
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.contexts">
      <context
            description="context scope"
            id="com.sap.adt.wda.controller.ui.contextScope"
            name="context scope"
            parentId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window">
      </context>
   </extension>
```

Activation and deactivation: It is done through activation and deactivation of context. Below is the code snippet on page change.

Activation in 1st Page:

```java
private void activateHandlers() {
            IContextService contextService = (IContextService) (PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IContextService.class));
            if (contextService != null) {
                activation = contextService.activateContext(IControllerConstants.CONTEXT_TAB_ECLIPSE_CONTEXT_ID);
            }
            IEditorSite site = getEditor().getEditorSite();
            IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) site.getService(IHandlerService.class);

            IHandlerActivation nodeActivation = service.activateHandler(AddNodeHandler.COMMAND_ID, new AddNodeHandler());
            activatedHandlers = new ArrayList<IHandlerActivation>();
            activatedHandlers.add(nodeActivation );

        }
```

Activation in 2nd Page:

```java
private void activateHandlers() {
                IContextService contextService = (IContextService) (PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IContextService.class));
                if (contextService != null) {
                    activation = contextService.activateContext(IControllerConstants.CONTEXT_TAB_ECLIPSE_CONTEXT_ID);
                }
                IEditorSite site = getEditor().getEditorSite();
                IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) site.getService(IHandlerService.class);


    IHandlerActivation methodActivation = service.activateHandler(AddMethodHandler.COMMAND_ID, new AddMethodHandler());
                activatedHandlers = new ArrayList<IHandlerActivation>();
                activatedHandlers.add(methodActivation );
            }
```

Deactivation similar in respective page:

```java
public void deactivateHandlers() {
            IContextService contextService = (IContextService) (PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IContextService.class));
            contextService.deactivateContext(activation);
            IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) getEditor().getEditorSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
            if (activatedHandlers != null) {
                service.deactivateHandlers(activatedHandlers);
                activatedHandlers = null;
            }
        }
```

Even after deactivation / activation on page change, the conflict appears.
Please let me know if there is a better approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different context id for each page. You could make your main `com.sap.adt.wda.controller.ui.contextScope` the parent of each page context.

Comment: Hi Greg,

It worked , but the context menu used in the page doesn't show the accelerator key 'Alt+O'. 
We have already set the Command ID.

    addActionNode.setActionDefinitionId(AddNodeActionHandler.COMMAND_ID);
    ((Action) addMethodAction).setActionDefinitionId(AddMethodHandler.COMMAND_ID);

Thanks.

Comment: What does `AddNodeHandler` do?